# Performance drops when adding a feature using XGBoost

Tags: feature-selection, dataset, boosting, feature-engineering

I did some feature engineering with my data set. When I added on of the new features, the performance significantly dropped. How is this possible? I thought XGBoost is robust to irrelevant variables.

Comment: You'll have to add a lot more detail than just this if you want any but the most generic answer :)   Well-tuned gradient boosting algorithms are in general robust - but not completely insensitive to - irrelevant variables that are largely uncorrelated with (in the Spearman sense) existing variables, but then again, so is linear regression.

Answer (score 2):

I think your understanding is mostly fine. :)

What you report is possible because GBM are not completely immune to irrelevant variables being included in their explanatory variables. For example, if we do not have many explanatory variables and we add an "uninformative variable" in our training set, if we keep the variable subsampling ratio the same as well as the number of iterations the same, we give less chances to our GBM to actually use informative variables. Effectively we do not allow our GBM to be tuned adequately.

Similarly, if we have a model performance estimate for our model that is generally variable (e.g. we perform 5-fold cross-validation once and our mean ROC-AUC estimate has somewhat high variance due to relative class imbalance) then adding  an "uninformative variable" can exaggerate this situation.